# Symfony: disable exceptions in prod mode

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony

I'm a beginner with Symfony.

I have a Symfony 3.1 project. I put y project on my remote server. Everything works fine. Then I use SensioLabsInsight to check errors in my project. This analyse tool gives me those 2 warnings messages

:
"Exceptions should not be enabled in production" and "Symfony applications should not contain a config.php file"

Then my first question is how can I disable Exceptions in production ? 
My second question is may I remove the config.php file in production (located in myBundle/web/config.php) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then my first question is how can I disable Exceptions in production ?

As far as I can see when searching this on Google, I think it's because the second parameter passed to `new AppKernel('prod', ...);` is `true`, which enables debug mode. Set it to `false`. (same applies to debug settings in `config_prod.yml`).

> My second question is may I remove the config.php file in production (located in myBundle/web/config.php) ?

Yes, also remove any front-controller (like `app_dev.php`) except from your production one. Remember: The standard edition is just a recommendation. Symfony doesn't force you any file or directory in the directory structure.

Comment: I had solved the problem by myself by searching in google. Because Your answer is right I vote for it.

Comment: @zm455 please accept the answer (if it's correct), this will help further visitors to quickly find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the new Symfony version, there is a new var ***APP_DEBUG***, which you send to Kernel in the second parameter.
Just add new var to your .env file

> APP_DEBUG=false

```
return new Kernel($context['APP_ENV'], (bool) $context['APP_DEBUG']);
```